# Onclick chama função 2 vezes após de alterar valor no modo desenvolvedor browser

Tags: javascript, html5

Segue o código:

```
<button onclick="myFunction(1)">Meu botão</button>

<script>
function myFunction(num) {
    alert(num);
}
</script>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/43mt9og8/

Qualquer pessoa pode alterar valor usando F12.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mudar número `myFunction(1)` para `myFunction(2)`, e depois clicar botão, chama a função javascript 2 vezes.

Cada vez que muda o número, vai gravando em algum lugar.(Se ele mudar 50 vezes, vai chamar a função com 50 vezes)

Existe maneira antes de chamar a função, verificar quantos números gravados ?

Comment: Código do lado cliente (neste caso javascript) está sempre à mercê de clientes "curiosos", podes dificultar, mas não podes evitar. Podes dificultar por exemplo tirando o atributo "onclick" do html, assim não fica tão visivel. Ex de brincar com o codigo do lado cliente no google: https://postimg.org/image/6xv0q6lml/

Comment: @Miguel, como o cara fez esse site ? http://www.galaxyrom.com/ , nem `f12` ou `botão mouse direito` não funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que você quer fazer é parar a propagação né, isso que eu entendi.

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38569422/how-to-stop-event-propagation-on-onclick-event-in-html-attribute

exemplo:

```
<div onclick="(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation(); })(event)">
```

no seu caso ficaria assim:

```
<button onclick="(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation(); myFunction(1); })">Meu botão</button>

<script>
function myFunction(num) {
    alert(num);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, se a sua preocupação é que os usuários não alterem seu código javascript, você precisará deum código como o abaixo. E se possível separe o arquivo javascript do arquivo html.

```
<button id="btnId">Meu botão</button>
<script>
    function myFunction(num) {
        alert(num);
    }
    document.getElementById('btnId').onclick = function(){
        myFunction(47);
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Oi @Bruno Gerotto, nessa caso não dá, pois cada botão tem seu valor aleatória.

Comment: Como são gerados esses valores aleatórios dos botões?